# Graphical representation with drag and drop functionality

Tags: c#, webforms

In my asp.net web application I want to create something like to give list of boxes(block) to user, and user can drag and make connectivity and on saving I should be able to get sequence like predecessor of blocks which user has created. Can you suggest me how to do that?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far?

Comment: No not yet.I am so confused and not sure what to do?

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways you can achieve this functionality.
it depends which one you want to choose.

You can make use of [jQueryui](http://api.jqueryui.com/draggable/)

[kendoui](http://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/dragdrop/index) is another alternate to achieve the same.

Comment: Yes drag and drop is possible with jQuery but not after making sequence of arrow and boxes using Drag and Drop I want to read the sequence like which box is connected and how it is?

Comment: Then in that case [sortable](http://jqueryui.com/sortable/) feature might be helpful in tracking down the sorting sequence.

Please let me know if you need more info on this.

Comment: I don't want the sorting. I want sequencing like there should be multiple splits and joins possible. So I am saving predecessor and successor for each boxes. Si I want that functionality to be done from user side and I should get this data in my db.